# I want to create a desktop base Application for geoprocessing and store result in PostgreSQL(postgis)!

Tags: gis, postgis

I wanted to know what all i need to create a **desktop application** for geoprocessing and to store it in postgis. I need to extract values from satellite images and store it in postgresql. So my basic questions is which all open sources software i need to use in order to develop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to Postgres using JDBC, so you can build your desktop application in Java or anything else that can connect to a postgres databasae. Postgres geospatial functionality comes from installing PostGIS functions on top of postgres, and so passing those functions back and forth can be done using anything that can process pg queries. You can use PHP if you want it web-based. You can also use QGIS, which has a native PostGIS connector, if you're doing traditional spatial analysis, but you don't need to create that, it's already there to do geoprocessing and store data in postgis.